# holes in NSRect

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have an NSRect being drawn on my custom view and I have another xib with a custom view and a draw rect that is on top of my other NSRect.  My question is is it possible to have the NSRect on top see through the one underneath it like creating a hole on the view underneath?
[image]

Comment: I don't know what you are asking for. Vague question; "see?" What do you want it to do?

Comment: If you post your code I'm sure someone can help you out.

Comment: is it possible to change the alpha value of the nsrect of the window underneath only where the other nsview and drawrect is on top like making a hole in the draw rect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CGRect b=CGRectMake(40, 50, 240, 150);
CGRect c=CGRectMake(100, 125, 80, 275);

 CGRect i=CGRectIntersection(c, b);
```

i is intersection rect now you can make UIView and set alpha of that view